# ConverterNotFoundException while trying to access LDAP data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap

I am trying to fetch the data from a LDAP server. Till now, I have been successfully able to connect to the server and get a list of all the records. But when I try to GET a single record, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [javax.naming.Name]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.convertId(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindById(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.lambda$invokeFindById$2(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:95) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
...
```

I have my LDAP config setup as such

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories(basePackages = "com.sayak.repository.ldap")
public class LdapConfig {
    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrls;

    @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
    private String ldapBaseDn;

    @Value("${ldap.username}")
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;

    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword;

    @Bean
    ContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl(ldapUrls);
        ldapContextSource.setBase(ldapBaseDn);
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal);
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword);
        return ldapContextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }
}
```

The entry for LDAP data is

```
@Entry(objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LdapUser {
    @Id
    private Name distinguishedName;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    private String commonName;

    @Attribute(name = "sn")
    private String surname;

    @Attribute(name = "givenName")
    private String givenName;

    @Attribute(name = "ou")
    private String organisationalUnit;

    @Attribute(name = "uid")
    private String userId;

    @Attribute(name = "mail")
    private String email;

    public LdapUser(LdapUser other) {
        this.distinguishedName = other.distinguishedName;
        this.commonName = other.commonName;
        this.surname = other.surname;
        this.givenName = other.givenName;
        this.organisationalUnit = other.organisationalUnit;
        this.userId = other.userId;
        this.email = other.email;
    }
}
```

And my repository is setup like

```
@Repository
public interface LdapUserRepository extends LdapRepository<LdapUser> {
    LdapUser findByCommonName(String commonName);
    List<LdapUser> findByCommonNameContainingIgnoreCase(String commonName);
}
```

When I make a GET request at `/ldapUsers`, I get a valid response like

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "ldapUsers": [
            {
                "commonName": "Katherine Ito",
                "surname": "Ito",
                "givenName": "Katherine",
                "organisationalUnit": "Peons",
                "userId": "ItoK",
                "email": "ItoK@ns-mail3.com",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:6332/api/v1/ldapUsers/cn=Katherine%20Ito,ou=Peons"
                    },
                    "ldapUser": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:6332/api/v1/ldapUsers/cn=Katherine%20Ito,ou=Peons"
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:6332/api/v1/ldapUsers"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:6332/api/v1/profile/ldapUsers"
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:6332/api/v1/ldapUsers/search"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I make a GET request to `/ldapUsers/cn=Katherine%20Ito,ou=Peons` (as evident by the `self.href` in the first response, it throws the error.

I know of the existence of `ConversionServiceConverterManager.StringToNameConverter` but for some reason, it doesn't seem to get triggered. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this post is quite old, but since it hasn't been answered yet, I'll try to add my 2ct, so maybe somebody else can benefit from it.

It looks like you need to add `@DnAttribute` annotations in order to tell `spring-data-ldap`, how to create the `javax.naming.Name`.

See apidoc for `@DnAttribute`:

> Indicates that a field is to be automatically populated to/from the distinguished name of an entry. Fields annotated with this annotation will be automatically populated with values from the distinguished names of found entries. Annotated fields must be of type String.
> For automatic calculation of the DN of an entry to work, the index() value must be specified on all DnAttribute annotations in that class, and these attribute values, prepended with the Entry.base() value will be used to figure out the distinguished name of entries to create and update.

and apidoc for `@Transient`:

> This annotation identifies a field in an Entry annotated class that should not be persisted to LDAP.

Supposed you root DN is `dc=example,dc=org`, and an entry looks like this (where the *distinguished name* consists of `uid`, `ou` and the `base DN`):

```
dn: uid=myUserId,ou=myUnit,dc=example,dc=org`
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: My User
givenName: My
sn: User
uid: myUserId
```

Then you should change you class to this:

```
@Entry(objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LdapUser {
    @Id
    private Name distinguishedName;

    @DnAttribute(value = "uid", index = 1)
    private String userId;

    @Transient
    @DnAttribute(value = "ou", index = 0)
    private String organisationalUnit;


    // ... other members unchanged
}
```

#### Explanation

##### Transient

Since `ou` is just part of the distinguished name, but should not be persisted as a property of the `inetOrgPerson` itself, `ou` needs to be `@Transient`.

`uid` on the other hand is an actual property that is not only part of you `dn`,
but also a real (non-transient) property of an `inetOrgPerson`. Thus this property is only annotated with `@DnAttribute`, but not with `@Transient`.

##### index

Since LDAP is hierarchial and `dc=example,dc=org` is your base dn, this looks like that in ldap:

```
 +-- dc=example,dc=org
 |   +-- ou=myUnit
 |   |   +-- uid=myUser
 |   |   \-- uid=anotherUser
```

Thus `ou` should have index 0 (first level under the base DN) and `uid` has index 1 (one level deeper).